# Is there a way to make this on a single url has multiple function call?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, routes

Is there a way to make this on a single url has multiple function call? I am using express+ejs+mongo in my work.

```
function bla(req, res){};
function blabla(req, res){};
function blablabla(req, res){};

function renderfunc(req, res) {
  res.render("index");
}
```

Following line works fine

```
app.get("/", bla, blabla, renderfunc);
```

but following line not works

```
app.get("/", bla, blabla, blablabla, renderfunc);
```

Only 2 functions can call in single url, then add one more function then it is not working anyway with all functions. I am not able to call three or more functions in single url.

I know this is a syntax mess, but just for giving an idea of what I would like to achieve?

Anyone know how to do this?

UPDATE:
I updated code just like this

```
function bla(req, res, next){
  console.log("bla");
  res.render("index", {orders: orders});
  next();
};

function blabla(req, res, next){
  console.log("blabla");
  res.render("index", {jobs: jobs});
  next();
  };

function blablabla(req, res, next){
  console.log("blablabla");
  res.render("index", {foods: foods});
  next();
  };

app.get("/", bla, blabla, blablabla);
```

when i running and inside terminal showing

```
bla
blabla
```

and still not showing result of console.log("blablabla"); still third function not calling again and added req.next() is not function error occured.

How do I call function blablabla()?

Comment: I updated my question please look at this

Answer (score 1):

If i understand right then you are trying to give multiple parameters in your link so like `exemple.com/param1/param2/param3` and if that is the case you do something as so

```
app.get("/:param1/:param2/:param3", (req, res) =>{
     var param1 = req.params.param1;
     /* And declare the rest as you want it*/
 });
```

And `param1` you can change it to what ever but then when you declare it you just change it. So lets you'r parameter is a `id` then you can just do `var ourParam= req.params.id` where the parameters name is after the `param`

Comment: No no not using multiple parameter on my single url. Using functions example function bla(req, res){} is just like function sort(req, res){} or blabla() is mean search()

Comment: I updated my question please look at this

Answer (score 0):

The number of function arguments is not the issue. Express allow a route to execute an unbounded number of handler functions in processing a request.

The problem here is that the path through the list of middleware functions is not being followed through to completion. This could be for a few reasons:

- Any function in the chain fails to call its `next` (i.e., the third argument supplied to a handler function, after `req` and `res`). Because a response may depend on asynchronous operations, the completion of a function's synchronous component does not mean that next handler may execute immediately; Express will wait until the handler's code calls `next` to signal that the current handler has completed its work.
- A function in the chain calls `next` with an argument (`next("foo")`) which halts processing of the current route (so any subsequent handler functions are never called) and begins processing the request according to the other specified route instead
- Possibly one of the intermediate function finalizes the response (e.g., by calling `res.redirect` or `res.end`) so that no later function can affect the request in any way. I would expect Express to raise an error in this case (but possibly the modification could be attempted in a `try` block).

It sounds like you have a particular handler function that is doing one of these things, rather than having too many handler functions. The example code that you've supplied won't work at all because none of the function supplied call `next`, and your actual code probably has a similar problem.

Comment: You mean i need to change like that?function bla(req, res, next){};
function blabla(req, res, next){};
function blablabla(req, res, next){};

function renderfunc(req, res) {
  res.render("index");
}

Comment: @ОтгонбаярЛамжав Yes, and actually call `next()` inside each of your functions when it's done doing its operations

Comment: I updated my question please look at this

Comment: @ОтгонбаярЛамжав This is the third possibly I suggest in my answer. Calling `res.render` twice causes an error because a full response has already been sent by the first `res.render`. You enter the second function but don't make it through it, because the second `render` call kills the task with an error (you may or may not be able to see the error due to your logging setup)